# Automatic Login with Janrain/OneAll/LoginRadius etc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, facebook-authentication, janrain, loginradius

I am planning to allow users to login to a website I am developing using their social network logins. Probably using one of the multi-provider services such as Janrain, OneAll, LoginRadius. What I want to know is, if a user of my site is already logged into their social network site when they visit my site, how do I go about automatically signing them in? The example I have come across that does this is goodreads.com.

I've developing in ASP.NET MVC3 but I would welcome any explanations/examples on how I go about this in any technology or even just the theory.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working at OneAll and I'm glad to answer your question.

After a user has logged in with Social Login, you create a new account in your database, you log the user in and you set a cookie.

When the same user comes back in a couple of days, you detect that he has a cookie and you use the cookie information to automatically log him him and you refresh the cookie.

Comment: Thanks for that, however goodreads manages to automatically log you in without the cookie so long as you are currently logged into your social site. E.g. if I open a new browser and clear all cookies, then I login to facebook, then I open goodreads (not for the first time obviously otherwise I wouldn't have a goodreads account), goodreads somehow detects that I am logged into facebook, and that my facebook account is linked to a goodreads account and then automatically logs me in to goodreads. A bit scary when one thinks about it - but that is what my client would like. Thanks

Comment: @claude, what about for iOS apps?  Is oneall relevant there?